# ios restrict app from iPhone 6 and 6+ deployment

Tags: ios

I have an app I've been working on for a while and now ready to release. Nonetheless, I don't want iPhone 6 or 6+ owners to be able to download it because it wasn't optimized yet for those devices. Please advice exactly on how to do this since I am using xCode6

Comment: There is no reason at all to prevent iPhone 6/6+ users from downloading your app. There are a million apps in the store that don't support the iPhone 6/6+ and they all work just fine that way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can stop them from downloading it. It should work -- it'll appear "zoomed" -- but, as you say, it won't be optimal.

Comment: I was reading something about UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities but unable to figure it out or if it even works to limit iPhone 6 and 6+

Comment: That can typically be used to exclude older devices or those without particular abilities (for example, you could exclude devices without a GPS chip), but I'm not aware of a way to exclude device that have "everything."

Comment: haha I like the double quotes. Thanks Stephen for clarifying.